# Get value of "data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I need to figure out the value of data strings with jquery, for example like this:

```
 { label: "Beginner",  data: 2},
 { label: "Advanced",  data: 12},
 { label: "Expert",  data: 22},
```

to add them up.

Something like:

```
var sum = data1+data2+data3;
alert(sum);
```

So the result for this example would be 36.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is this inside JSON or you just have a number of these strings or...?

Comment: What you posted...is it a large, single string, an array of strings?  With the trailing command there it makes it hard to know what the input looks like.

Comment: its connected to flot pie chart, the correct part of the code is something like that:

$.plot($("#experience"), [
        { label: "Beginner",  data: 2},
        { label: "Advanced",  data: 12},
 { label: "Expert",  data: 22},

 ], 

with the value for the data set by me.
sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

```
var data = [
   { label: "Beginner",  data: 2},
   { label: "Advanced",  data: 12},
   { label: "Expert",  data: 22} 
]
var sum = 0;

for each (var d in data) {
    sum += d.data;
}

alert(sum);
```